# When should I use tempfile

Tags: python

I have a quick question about Python `tempfile`.

When shoudl I use tempfile? If I use `tempfile.mkstemp` to create a temporary file, is this same as a normal file? What are the differences? Thanks.

Comment: did you already read the documentation? http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) pretty much says it all. In my view, you should use `tempfile` when you need to create a file but don't care about its name. You can have the file deleted automatically when you're done or saved, if you wish. It can also be visible to other programs or not.

Answer (score 0):

This article has a good explanation on what it's used for.

http://pythoncentral.org/using-the-python-tempfile-module/

The first paragraph provides a good summary

> While programming in Python, there will likely be times where you have some data that needs to be utilized or manipulated in the form of
>   a file but hasn’t yet been written to one. Naturally, the first
>   solution that comes to mind is to open a new or existing file, write
>   the data and finally save it (if you’re unfamiliar with how to do this
>   take a look at the article Reading and Writing Files in Python).
>   However, it might also be the case that once your script(s) are
>   finished running, you don’t need or want the file(s) anymore, and
>   therefore, don’t want it hanging around in your or anyone else’s file
>   system.

Answer (score 0):

From [Learning Python](http://oreilly.com/catalog/lpython/chapter/ch09.html):

Using Temporary Files

> If you've ever written a shell script and needed to use intermediary
>   files for storing the results of some intermediate stages of
>   processing, you probably suffered from directory litter. You started
>   out with 20 files called log_001.txt, log_002.txt etc., and all you
>   wanted was one summary file called log_sum.txt. In addition, you had a
>   whole bunch of log_001.tmp, log_001.tm2, etc. files that, while they
>   were labeled temporary, stuck around. At least that's what we've seen
>   happen in our own lives. To put order back into your directories, use
>   temporary files in specific directories and clean them up afterwards.
>
> To help in this temporary file-management problem, Python provides a
>   nice little module called tempfile that publishes two functions:
>   mktemp() and TemporaryFile(). The former returns the name of a file
>   not currently in use in a directory on your computer reserved for
>   temporary files (such as /tmp on Unix or C:\TMP on Windows). The
>   latter returns a new file object directly.